# These credentials do not authorize access

Tags: here-api

I signed up in here.com developer program and created a project on 21st November 2017. I have got my APP_ID and APP_CODE from the developer console for that project and I am using those in the request below.

https://wse.cit.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?start=50.0715%2C8.2434&destination1=50.1073%2C8.6647&destination2=49.8728%2C8.6326&destination3=50.0505%2C8.5698&destination4=50.1218%2C8.9298&end=50.0021%2C8.259&improveFor=time&mode=fastest%3Bcar&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE

When I run this request I keep getting the following message:

{"faultCode":"s6a22042f-3092-40a9-94c4-1de81b80eea4","responseCode": "403","message":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com."}

In the developer console it states it might take 1 hour for the APP_ID and APP_CODE to be completely registered and it's already 2 days and I am still getting that message.

Could you please help what I need to do to make this work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Production environment, where the credentials are valid and would be working. Production environment will not contain the "cit" in the url.

https://**wse.api.here.com**/2/findsequence.json?start=50.0715%2C8.2434&destination1=50.1073%2C8.6647&destination2=49.8728%2C8.6326&destination3=50.0505%2C8.5698&destination4=50.1218%2C8.9298&end=50.0021%2C8.259&improveFor=time&mode=fastest%3Bcar&app_id=App_Id&app_code=App_Code